# Value multiplo com separação por virgula

Tags: php

Seguinte, estou usando setcookie afim de pegar ids de todas as páginas visitadas por usuário e assim fazer uma especie de histórico, porem me deparo com um problema quando não a possibilidade de atualizar o value do cookie adicionando novos id de página no mesmo nome.

Sempre que o valor, "3", muda o cookie muda para o proximo valor, teria como o 3 continuar e o novo valor aparecer depois de uma virgula?

```
<?php 
setcookie("id", "3");
print_r($_COOKIE); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você concatenar os valores.

```
$id = $_COOKIE["id"];
$novoId = "Novo-Valor";

if (!preg_match("/\b{$novoId}\b/", $id)) {
    setcookie("id", $id .= ",{$novoId}");
}
```

E para separar:

```
var_dump( explode(",", $_COOKIE["id"]) );
```

Comment: ele esta duplicando os id

Comment: @Gabriel atualizei minha resposta. Adicionei uma verificação para cadastrar somente novos valores.

Comment: So tenho a agradecer cara, muito obrigado.